# Parsing graphical interfaces of Windows based executables

Tags: windows, user-interface, parsing

- I want to parse the graphical interfaces that pop up during the execution of Windows based installers.
- I want to retrieve the information that gets displayed on the pop up windows without of course taking up a subpar solution like OCR.
- Are there any well known APIs provided by Microsoft or other open source solutions?

Comment: Will the Microsoft Active Accessibility SDK work or do you need something different? if you need something different then please explain why so we can provide something that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: It seems that Microsoft Active Accessibility SDK is only supported for Windows 2000 and older versions. Are "Windows UI automation APIs the new way around?" If so, what SDK needs to be downloaded and do we have any reference documentation to try out the examples in the SDK?